atoi present with just iostream in C++ (not documented)
basically the title. cppreference and other sources state it is present with cstdlib but the following bit of code:
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  atoi(argv[1]);
}

compiles with no problem. why is that? looking at the preprocessor output, it seems like atoi is available in an extern "C" block.
is this atoi different from std::atoi?

C++ allows any standard header to have the effect of including any other standard header(s). So your code is allowed to work, but not guaranteed.

In fact it's a very common thing for me: I usually get some errors about missing headers, so I add them. Then I update my Windows build, and get new errors about missing headers because VisualC++ has entirely different headers than g++ does. I'm sure I'm still not including ALL the headers that are technically required, but...

Don't use atoi(). In C++ use std::stoi instead

@phuclv actually, depending on context, I often refrain from using locale-supporting behemoths (even though I'm hoping that my initial std::locale::global(std::locale::classic()); will avoid problems). As such, I'm a big fan of std::from_chars (as well as it's companion std::to_chars) -- these would even do the right thing if I still needed locale support...

The C++ standard library is allowed to include symbols it needs and include even other headers of the standard library. However, this is not standard and not guaranteed to be the case on other compilers.
For example, memcpy is "officially" only available through #include <string.h> or #include <cstring>, but because it is such a fundamental function in the standard library, many library headers include it indirectly.
But you are supposed to use #include <cstring> or #include <string.h>, because only that guarantees you to have this function available.

atoi is in cstdlib, not cstring.

@rustyx and where did i mention atoi?

#include <string.h> is a C header while #include <cstring> is a C++ header. Since this question is tagged C++, the correct header for your example is #include <cstring>.

@FrançoisAndrieux the Question was tagged with c/c++ before
